# Comparing two files with different column layouts

Tags: bash, diff

I have two flat files. A.txt, B.txt

In A.txt, I have:

```
Name,reg no,address

A, 001, ABC, xyz, AA
B, 002, BBC, xxx, BB
```

In B.txt, I have:

```
Name,reg no,address

A, 001, ABC, xyz, AA
B, 002, BBC,xxx,BB
```

How can I compare these two files?

Comment: Why not use simple `cmp` or `diff`?

Comment: What do you mean by *same or not*? You have the header row to deal with. Are you wanting to ignore that and just compare the data?

Comment: A.txt(A,001) = B.txt(A,001)

Comment: A.txt(A,001) (Street) == B.txt(A,001)(address(Street))

Comment: We have to prove like if address has (Street), (city),(state)

Comment: Show us what you already tried, we are not goint to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 2):

If the only difference between the two files is the commas, try passing each through "tr" to remove them:

```
cat A.txt | tr -d ',' > A.filtered.txt
```

Save each as a temporary file and then use 'diff' or more processing to make them similar.  If the rows are out of order you can sort them before comparison.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in just comparing them and not bother about how they differ, you could use `cmp`:

```
if ! cmp -s A.txt B.txt; then
  echo "The files differ"
else
  echo "The files are same"
fi
```

Comment: The name and reg no in both the files are same.. Bt there are 3 columns A(Street name,city,state) to which u have to check with b(address)